# Check if item is delivered to a specific country or not using Amazon API?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am currently using  [Amazon Product Advertising API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ProgrammingGuide.html) to scrape multiple fields.

I know we can grab Availability, AvailabilityType, MaximumHours, MinimumHours fields but this does not fulfill my requirement.

I have a separate Python Scrapy script which emulates this button's behavior to check if item is shipped to Australia or not.

[image]

**So I wonder if there is any of Amazon's API to check if an item is shipped to a particular country or not?**